# Google image charts - misaligned data when compared to Y axis

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization

This is hopefully a simple fix, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the Google image charts API to figure it out.

Anyway. The Chart is below with the code used to generate it below that.

[Google Image Chart](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chds=a&chf=bg,s,EFEFEF&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxr=2,44,140&chxl=0%3a|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|1%3a|Grouped%20by%20Day|3%3a|Hits&chxp=1,50|3,59&chs=550x300&chd=t:117,60,95,114,82,97,87,75,90,82,75,86,81,100,112,94,109,82,59,94&chm=N,000000,0,-1,10,,c%3a:17.888543819998&chtt=User+Activity%3A+14%2F10%2F2013+%E2%80%93+02%2F11%2F2013)

Here is the url code broken into lines:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
cht=lc&
chds=a&
chf=bg,s,EFEFEF&
chxt=x,x,y,y&
chxr=2,44,140&
chxl=0:|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|1:|Grouped%20by%20Day|3:|Hits&
chxp=1,50|3,59&
chs=550x300&
chd=t:117,60,95,114,82,97,87,75,90,82,75,86,81,100,112,94,109,82,59,94&
chm=N,000000,0,-1,10,,c::18
&chtt=User+Activity%3A+14%2F10%2F2013+–+02%2F11%2F2013
```

so yeah as you can see if you click the link (not enough rep to post the image im afraid), the data is misaligned. The data is being displayed as if it the vertical bar is set to start at 0 and finish at ~120.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your [chds](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#data_scaling) parameter. When you set the [chrx](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#axis_scale) parameter, you need to set the other as well.

[This chart](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chds=44,140&chf=bg,s,EFEFEF&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxr=2,44,140&chxl=0%3a|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|1%3a|Grouped%20by%20Day|3%3a|Hits&chxp=1,50|3,59&chs=550x300&chd=t:117,60,95,114,82,97,87,75,90,82,75,86,81,100,112,94,109,82,59,94&chm=N,000000,0,-1,10,,c%3a:17.888543819998&chtt=User+Activity%3A+14%2F10%2F2013+%E2%80%93+02%2F11%2F2013) should work for you.